# How can I get the index of a given combination?

Tags: c, math, combinations, combinatorics, binomial-coefficients

I have a sequence of arrays of numbers with 5 elements each, from 0 to 8, and I have to order than using that combination, I mean:

```
i=0, {0,0,0,0,0}
i=1, {0,0,0,0,1}
i=2, {0,0,0,0,2}
i=3, {0,0,0,0,3}
i=4, {0,0,0,0,4}
i=5, {0,0,0,0,5}
i=6, {0,0,0,0,6}
i=7, {0,0,0,0,7}
i=8, {0,0,0,0,8}
i=9, {0,0,0,1,1}
     ...
i=1285, {7,8,8,8,8}
i=1286, {8,8,8,8,8}
```

so if I give {0,0,1,1,2} to the function it's returns 7.
I thought about using the [Combinatorial number system](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Combinatorial_number_system) 
but I'm missing something that I don't know what it is, the code below just doesn't work

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define size 1287

int combination[9][5] =     {
                    {0,  0,   0,      0,      0},
                    {1,  1,   1,      1,      1},
                    {2,  3,   4,      5,      6},
                    {3,  3,   6,     15,     21},
                    {4, 10,  20,     35,     56},
                    {5, 15,  35,     70,    126},
                    {6, 21,  56,    126,    252},
                    {7, 28,  84,    210,    462},
                    {8, 36, 120,    330,    792}
                };

int getKey(int array[]){
    int key=0;
    int tempArray[9] = {0};
    for(int i=0;i<5;i++){
        tempArray[array[i]]++;
    }
    int j=0;
    for(int i=0;i<9;i++){
        if(tempArray[i]!=0){
            while(tempArray[i]!=0){
                array[j++] = i;
                key += combination[i][5-j];
                tempArray[i]--;
            }
        }
    }
    return key;
}

int main(){
  int it[5];
  for(it[0]  = 0 ;it[0]<9;it[0]++){
    for(it[1]=it[0];it[1]<9;it[1]++){
      for(it[2]=it[1];it[2]<9;it[2]++){
        for(it[3]=it[2];it[3]<9;it[3]++){
          for(it[4]=it[3];it[4]<9;it[4]++){
            printf("{%d %d %d %d %d} = %d\n",it[0],it[1],it[2],it[3],it[4],getKey(it));
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
  return 0;
}
```

Obs: I'm using counting sort to keep the lexicographic order, in theory I will receive unsorted arrays.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I will give you the Answer I wrote for the previous version of this question which you posted yesterday and deleted. (And that's bad form, by the way.)

Let's call the binomial coefficient C(n, k) = n!/(k!(n-k)!)

The number of unordered strings of m letters drawn from an alphabet of s symbols is C(m+s-1, s-1). Let's call that D(m, s). In this case, D(5, 9) = C(5+9-1, 9-1) = C(13, 8) = 1287

Let's sort each string, then number them:

```
aaaaa 1
aaaab 2
aaaac 3
...
aaaai 9
aaabb 10
aaabc 11
...
```

If a string contains 5 a's, its number is D(5, 1) = C(5+1-1, 1-1) = C(5, 0) = 1.
If a string contains 4 a's, its number is 1 plus a number determined by the non-a letter, which goes up to D(1,8) = C(1+8-1,8-1) = C(8, 7) = 8. So they go up to 1+8=9. 
If a string contains 3 a's, its number is 9 plus a number determined by the non-a letters, which goes up to D(2,8) = C(9,7) = 36, so 9+36=45.
If a string contains 2 a's, its number is in [46,165].
If a string contains 1 a, its number is in [166, 495].
If a string contains no a, its number is in [496, 1287].

So how about the string "aabgg"? It's number is (45)+(8)+(7)+(6)+(5)+(4)+(1)=76

No collisions, and the calculation of the index is O(sm(s+m)), which is not too bad for m=5 and s=9.

**EDIT:** to clarify, let's define

```
E(j, m, s) = D(0,s-1)+D(1,s-1)+...+D(m-j-1,s-1)
```

Suppose a string of m letters drawn from an alphabet of s symbols contains j of the first letter of the alphabet. There are E(j,m,s) strings in the catalogue *before the first such string.* For instance, before the first string that begins with exactly two a's ("aabbb"), there are E(2, 5, 9)=45 strings.

To get to "aabbb" we must count out 45 strings.
To get from "aabbb" to the next string that contains exactly one b ("aabcc"), we must count out E(1, 3, 8) = 8 strings.
From there to the next string that contains no c ("aabdd"), E(0, 2, 7) = 7 strings.
No d ("aabee"): E(0, 2, 6) = 6
No e ("aabff"): E(0, 2, 5) = 5
No f ("aabgg"): E(0, 2, 4) = 4
And we must count "aabgg" itself: 1

Comment: I really apologize, I showed the question to a friend of mine and he said that there were so many mistakes in English that it was better to rewrite, so I took advantage and wrote in a simpler way

Comment: where did this "(8)+(7)+(6)+(5)+(4)+(1)" came from in the example?

Comment: How E(2,5,9) = 45? if E(2,5,9) = D(3,8)+D(4,8)+D(5,8) =  C(10,7)+C(11,7)+C(12,7) = 120+330+792 = 1242

Comment: @NedLandy: sorry, I transcribed the algebra wrong. I'll edit.

Answer (score 0):

well, I think this look like oct number 1...8

```
0 = {00000}
1 = {00001}
2 = {00002}
8 = {00010}
```

if this what you mean

I think this algorithm is the best

```
   int get_key(int a[5]){
      int idx, rval=0;
      for(i=4; i<=0; i--)
         rval += powl(a[i], i);
      return rval; 
   }
```

Comment: the problem in this case is that {0 0 0 0 1} = {0 0 0 1 0}, what didn't happen with the oct number